# Is it possible to get .NET Core solution's nuget package versions programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, versioning

I'm developing an endpoint to provide some app info. One of the requirements is to get version of one specific nuget package we use.

I've tried to do so thru `Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof()).GetName().Version.ToString()`but this package's version differs from it's assembly version, so it's no use to me.

Comment: prolly you can't ... assembly is not aware of their  nuget package ...

Comment: if you are using MSBuild you can: use build time variable and use it as nuget package version and use `WriteLinesToFile` to write this version to the file ... then you can embed this file to your assebly and read this value

Comment: The info is in your project.assets.json file, if you make sure that's bundled with your release artifact you could read it from there. Not sure if there's a better way

Comment: [...like this](https://gist.github.com/SelvinPL/2e64ff23ffd188bd528733d019ce4275)